# C++ program does not show output until it terminates

Tags: c++, xcode

I have written a c++ program in Xcode. It is something like this:

```
int main()
{
   func();
}
void func()
{
   while(true)
   {
      cout<<"Something here";
      if(func2()==1)
          return true;
   }
}

//some func2() function
int func2(){
   static int i=100;
   i--;
   return i
}
```

This is not the exact program. It is just a model of what I did. I do not expect the program to terminate early but I expect it print "Something here" on the screen so that I know the progress of the program. But it does not print anything. When instead of infinite loop, I tried the loop for 10 times, it printed 10 "Something here" after the program terminated. So I am guessing its not outputting to the console immediately. Also, when I look in the debug area, func2 is actually being called many times. So the program is working the way I expected, just not printing things immediately. I am not sure why is this happening? Has anybody else experienced this with Xcode?

Comment: Implicit `int`, as in the declaration `main()`, is not valid in C++. Fixed that for you. Please post only valid code (modulo the problem to be solved) that readers can try. This also goes for the declaration `func()`. I left that as is because it's arbitrary code, not a stock phrase.

Comment: Try `cout<<"Something here" << std::flush;`

Comment: @user1320881That works! Thank you :)

Comment: Thee is no point in posting code that is *roughly like* the code causing the error. (I doubt that code will produce the error tbh) By the sound of the description it's probably buffering the output for efficiency reasons. It'll likely output whenever you send a new-line character or when you ask for input.

Comment: I would have posted exact code but its a large code base that used many functions and variables not even in the same file. i just wanted to know the conceptual reason of why this happens. Your and @user1320881 answers solved my problem and I also understood what exactly was happening. Thanks :)

Comment: @s_123 You only need to post example code that produces the error. If you put the code you posted through a compiler you would discover that what you posted does not produce the error you reported in the question. So all I was saying was that it is better to not post code at all than to post different code to the code producing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cout` output is buffered: it stores data in memory and periodically flushes its buffer into the actual output file. You can force flush by sending a `flush` manipulator, an `endl` manipulator (newline + flush) or by calling `cout.flush()` manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just move `func()` on top of the `main()` block